# Count and Avg the number of records in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sum

Hey guys, I need some help with this. I have a table with about 100k records. Each row is referenced by an ID. Here is an example

```
Keyword     | Domain          | Page | UserID
Hello       | www.example.com |    1 |   994
World       | www.example.com |    1 |   994
Genius      | www.example.com |    1 |   994
Example map | www.example.com |    2 |   994
Hello       | www.example.com |    1 |   994
demo0       | www.test.com    |    1 |   994
demo1       | www.test.com    |    2 |   994
demo2       | www.test.com    |    2 |   994
demo3       | www.test.com    |    3 |   994
wonderful   | www.mysql.com   |    1 |   997
wonder      | www.mysql.com   |    1 |   997
SOFLOW      | www.mysql.com   |    1 |   997
```

What I want to see is how many (single number) keywords appear on Page 1, 2 or 3 for a user.

Here is an example output:

```
User | Domain          | Total KW | #Page 1 | #Page 2 | # Page3
 994 | www.example.com |        5 |       3 |       1 |       0
 994 | www.test.com    |        4 |       1 |       2 |       1
```

I know I can do this in PHP, but is there any way to do this in MySQL? I can get the avg and the count but I cant get what I want :(

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT User, Domain, COUNT(Page),
    SUM(IF(Page=1, 1, 0)) AS Page1,
    SUM(IF(Page=2, 1, 0)) AS Page2,
    SUM(If(Page=3, 1, 0)) AS Page3
FROM table
GROUP BY User, Domain
```

This would get tedious if there's more than just these 3 "pages". At that point you should just group on the page as well, count them normally without the SUM stuff, and then do the multi-column formatting in your application.